# android studio 3.0 unable to create activities

Tags: android, android-studio, freemarker

With the upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 from Android Studio 2.3.3 where I had edited this file simple.xml.ftl to use RelativeLayout and not ConstraintLayout all worked fine until the update I will post the two ftl file formats below. My question is why is this happening? I have looked at the error log and have very little desire to learn ftl syntax Would someone copy the code in this file that has Android Studio 2.3.3 or 3.0 and post it as an answer. The path to this file is"AndroidStudio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities/common/root/res/layout
  /simple.xml.ftl"
Open the file with Notepad or Sublime Text and copy the contents.

This is what my original file looked like

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   <#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
   tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
   </#if>
   tools:context="${relativePackage}.${fragmentClass}">

   <#if isNewProject!false>
   <TextView
   <#if includeCppSupport!false>
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
   </#if>
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </#if>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  This is my change that worked until Android Studio 3.0

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  <#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
  </#if>


  tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClpackageNamsNewProject!false>
    <TextView
    <#if includeCppSupport!false>
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    </#if>
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </#if>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Fine to vote the question down I tried numerous edits on the FTL file to construct the correct syntax all failed so voting the question down as a result of me not boring people with failed attempts and I have looked at numerous SO post that addressed the process the fact that I know how to fix the issue should say I did some research

Comment: @ddekany If I post the error can you suggest correct FTL syntax for this question or share the simple.xml.ftl file so I can go back to writing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the faults in your Relative Layout simple.xml.ftl file I will post my file with the change to Relative Layout it works great First I will post your code the My Code One BIG suggestion do a SAVE AS from Sublime Text and replace the file DO NOT open the file and try to save the code that way just from past experience with an other NetBeans file

Your code

```
  tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClpackageNamsNewProject!false>
```

My Code

```
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">
```

Here is the complete code let us know if it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
</#if>
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

<#if isNewProject!false>
<TextView
<#if includeCppSupport!false>
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
</#if>
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</#if>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that line of code you posted as different from the original with no results I will save the file as suggested I think I opened the file to save the first time Thank You Google responded and made this a BUG Android Studio 3.0 is neat but not as stable as it should be